# Searching for a superview inside UITableViewCell iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I had a custom `UItableViewCell` class named `EditableTableViewCell` that (besides other things) has a `UITextField` inside added to its `contentView`. In the `Textfield` delegate method I'm trying to detect to which section it belongs to. Like this:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    UIView* contentView =[textField superview];
    //traverse up in the view hierarchy until we find the cell's content view.
    while (![contentView isKindOfClass:[EditableTableViewCell class]] || contentView.superview == nil) {
        contentView = [contentView superview];
    }
    EditableTableViewCell *thiscell = (EditableTableViewCell*)contentView;
    NSIndexPath *indexpath =[[self tableView]indexPathForRowAtPoint:thiscell.center];
```

This gives me the correct result and I saw a similar solution 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962771/getting-uitableviewcell-with-superview-in-ios-7) that also navigates the view hierarchy. I'm wondering if this is the only solution or if there's something more appropriate that doesn't involve looping for all the available cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, no need to loop through the view

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    UIView* contentView =[textField superview];
    CGPoint center = [self.tableView convertPoint:textField.center fromView:contentView];
    NSIndexPath *indexpath =[[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:center];
    NSLog(@"indexPath:%@", indexpath);
}
```

Comment: you should put the @ before the NSLog. I tried editing it but It doesn't let me. This works, but i don't know if it's more efficient, since my implementation also works. Do you know how to test this?

Comment: yes, Thanks, just edit the codes.   "c string" is a C string , but not a NSString, I am sorry for that

Comment: my codes should be more generic, and your codes rely on EditableTableViewCell,

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
NSIndexPath *indexpath = [(UITableView*)self.superview indexPathForCell:self]
```

?

Comment: well, because before iOS7 the cell was found like textfield.superview.superview; otherwise the indexpath always returned 0

Comment: .superview is a code smell to me. .superview.superview is a real stink. A project I'm working on had lots of this and it's broken now in iOS 7. It smelt like a problem, and it ended up being a problem. There is always a better way than doing .superview, which is lazy.

Comment: Which object is the delegate of the text view? The cell itself or the view controller?

Comment: @bandejapaisa I agree. There is bad design here in the question.

Comment: @bandejapaisa I also think is bad, but the other alternative was tags, which I also don't like very much, specially with tableviewcells that get created and deleted. By the way, nice nickname ;) la bandeja paisa rules!

Comment: @LeoNatan the view controller.