# How to make each cell of a UItableView to be 2 different buttons?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView and want to separate each cell in two buttons, one will be the thumbnail and the other the rest of the cell as usually, so it have to fire 2 different didSelectRowAtIndexPath methods depending on which button was pressed, how can I do that? Thank you

Comment: You need to add handler on the buttons and use the tag to identify individual buttons in the table. Solution for one button is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell - you will have to be more creative to come up with tags that identify not only row in the table but also which of the two buttons it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use tag for UIbutton selector method

Answer (score 0):

what is understand from your question is that you have two buttons in each cell in the uitableview , and you want two different actions when any button is pressed , so you neded to implement two different actions for each button it is straight forward , also check [this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) tutorial on how to implement a custom uitableviewcell