# UIButton action in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parsing

I am trying to run an action for a button being pressed within a table view cell. The following code is in my table view controller class.

The button has been described as "yes" in an outlet in my class of UITableViewCell called requestsCell.

I am using Parse to save data and would like to update an object when the button is pressed. My objectIds array works fine, the cell.yes.tag also prints the correct number to the logs, however, I cannot get that number into my "connected" function in order to run my query properly.

I need a way to get the indexPath.row of the cell to find the proper objectId.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as requestsCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.name.text = requested[indexPath.row]

    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

            cell.userImage.image = image
        }else{
            println("not working")
        }    
    }

    cell.yes.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.yes.targetForAction("connected", withSender: self)

    println(cell.yes.tag)

    return cell
}


func connected(sender: UIButton!) {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Contacts")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectIDs[sender.tag]) {
        (gameScore: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            gameScore["connected"] = "yes"
            gameScore.save()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See my [answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51735885/1966109) that shows up to 5 different ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

**Swift 4 & Swift 5:**

You need to add target for that button.

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And of course you need to set tag of that button since you are using it.

```
myButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

You can achieve this by subclassing UITableViewCell. Use it in interface builder, drop a button on that cell, connect it via outlet and there you go.

To get the tag in the connected function:

```
@objc func connected(sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
}
```

Comment: How do i get the tag, in the connected function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @André updated my answer for you, there might be some syntax errors, but this is general idea on how to get it.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I believe this is not possible anymore in Swift 2. As it says in the docs: When you call this method, target is not retained.

Comment: @Andrej Rather than using 'action: "connected:"' you have to use 'action: #selector(ClassName.FunctionName(_:)'

Comment: Do you know why the sender.tag is always 0?

Comment: what if i have sections and i need to know the section as well as the row

Comment: Working Answer Guys (Swift 4), Thanks

Comment: This selector and @objc business is getting really confusing. Can't believe how many silent or hard-to-trace failures there are with this. Can't it just take a block?

Answer (score 53):

The accepted answer using `button.tag` as information carrier which button has actually been pressed is solid and widely accepted but rather limited since a tag can only hold `Int`s.

You can make use of Swift's awesome closure-capabilities to have greater flexibility and cleaner code.

I recommend this article: [How to properly do buttons in table view cells using Swift closures](https://web.archive.org/web/20160730215620/http://candycode.io/how-to-properly-do-buttons-in-table-view-cells-using-swift-closures/) by Jure Zove.

Applied to your problem:

1. Declare a variable that can hold a closure in your tableview **cell** like

   ```
   var buttonTappedAction : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
   ```
2. Add an action when the button is pressed that only executes the closure. You did it programmatically with `cell.yes.targetForAction("connected", withSender: self)` but I would prefer an `@IBAction` outlet :-)

   ```
   @IBAction func buttonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
      tapAction?(self)
   }
   ```
3. Now pass the content of `func connected(sender: UIButton!) { ... }` as a closure to `cell.tapAction = {<closure content here...>}`. Please refer to the article for a more precise explanation and please don't forget to break reference cycles when capturing variables from the environment.

Comment: I think this method a lot more than the `tag` approach. I always thought that way was finicky.

Comment: It's very nice approach! Thanks...+1

Answer (score 45):

Simple and easy way to detect button event and perform some action

```
class youCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var yourobj : (() -> Void)? = nil

    //You can pass any kind data also.
   //var user: ((String?) -> Void)? = nil

     override func awakeFromNib()
        {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        }

 @IBAction func btnAction(sender: UIButton)
    {
        if let btnAction = self.yourobj
        {
            btnAction()
          //  user!("pass string")
        }
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = youtableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? youCell
        cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

cell!. yourobj =
            {
                //Do whatever you want to do when the button is tapped here
                self.view.addSubview(self.someotherView)
        }

cell.user = { string in
            print(string)
        }

return cell

}
```

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: Thank you Vincent. :)

Comment: @R.Mohan Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

We can create a closure for the button and use that in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
class ClosureSleeve {
  let closure: () -> ()

  init(attachTo: AnyObject, closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
    self.closure = closure
    objc_setAssociatedObject(attachTo, "[\(arc4random())]", self,.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
}

@objc func invoke() {
   closure()
 }
}

extension UIControl {
func addAction(for controlEvents: UIControlEvents = .primaryActionTriggered, action: @escaping () -> ()) {
  let sleeve = ClosureSleeve(attachTo: self, closure: action)
 addTarget(sleeve, action: #selector(ClosureSleeve.invoke), for: controlEvents)
 }
}
```

And then in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = youtableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? youCell
    cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none//swift 4 style

      button.addAction {
       //Do whatever you want to do when the button is tapped here
        print("button pressed")
      }

    return cell
 }
```

Comment: looks like cool trick, but this gives event 2 times.

Answer (score 6):

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var oneButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var twoButton: UIButton!
}


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.oneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.oneTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.twoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.twoTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func oneTapped(_ sender: Any?) {

    print("Tapped")
}

func twoTapped(_ sender: Any?) {

    print("Tapped")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With **Swift 5** this is what, worked for me!!

Step 1. Created IBOutlet for UIButton in My CustomCell.swift

```
class ListProductCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var productMapButton: UIButton!
//todo
}
```

Step 2. Added action method in CellForRowAtIndex method and provided method implementation in the same view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListProductCell") as! ListProductCell
cell.productMapButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ListViewController.onClickedMapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
return cell
    }

@objc func onClickedMapButton(_ sender: Any?) {

        print("Tapped")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Apple DOC](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/targetForAction:withSender:)

> targetForAction:withSender: 
> Returns the target object that responds to
>   an action.

You can't use that method to set target for `UIButton`.
Try 
[addTarget(_:action:forControlEvents:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:) method

Answer (score 1):

Get cell like this, Hope it will help someone

```
@objc func addActionClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    let buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: trustedTableView)
    let indexPath = trustedTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let cell = trustedTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! addNetworkSSIDCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 4

in cellForRowAt indexPath:

```
 cell.prescriptionButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("onClicked:"), for: .touchUpInside)
```

function that run after user pressed button:

```
@objc func onClicked(sender: UIButton){
        let tag = sender.tag


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good and simple approach but have limitation of information it can hold with tag. As sometime more information needed.

You can create a custom button and add properties as many as you like they will hold info you wanna pass:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var orderNo = -1
    var clientCreatedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
}
```

Make button of this type in Storyboard or programmatically:

```
protocol OrderStatusDelegate: class {
    func orderStatusUpdated(orderNo: Int, createdDate: Date)
}

class OrdersCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnBottom: CustomButton!
    weak var delegate: OrderStatusDelegate?
}
```

While configuring the cell add values to these properties:

```
 func configureCell(order: OrderRealm, index: Int) {
     btnBottom.orderNo = Int(order.orderNo)
     btnBottom.clientCreatedDate = order.clientCreatedDate
 }
```

When tapped access those properties in button's action (within cell's subclass) that can be sent through delegate:

```
@IBAction func btnBumpTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let button = sender as? CustomButton {
        let orderNo = button.orderNo
        let createdDate = button.clientCreatedDate
        delegate?.orderStatusUpdated(orderNo: orderNo, createdDate: createdDate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer another approach for getting the cell from a button within it.

The idea is to subclass `UIButton` only to open a `weak` pointer to a `UITableViewCell`.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    @objc weak var cell: UITableViewCell?
}
```

In the `UITableViewCell`:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    myButton.cell = self
}
```

In the `ViewController` of the table view, where the button is connected:

```
@IBAction func myButtonAction(sender: MyButton) {
    let parentCell = sender.cell
    ...
}
```