# Swift - Function from another class is not called when UIButton is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

Complete newbie here, and I'm trying to make a button from a tabelViewCell display its row number when pressed.

Here's the code from tableViewCell:

```
    var myTableViewController: tableViewController?

    @IBOutlet var addButton: UIButton!


    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) { 
    myTableViewController?.addCellToHome(self) //call add function
}
```

And from tableViewController:

```
func addCellToHome(_ cell: UITableViewCell) //specifies what is to be done when addButton is pressed
{

    let row = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

    print(row as! String)
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I inserted a breakpoint inside addCellToHome and turns out it's never called. Completed stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift Button action in table view cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894765/ios-swift-button-action-in-table-view-cell)

Comment: Are you sure the IBAction is being called?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Yes definitely. In my original code from tableViewCell it had `self.addButton.isEnabled = false` and when the button is pressed it greys out.

Comment: The code you posted does not make sense. Each time the user taps the add button, you instantiate a new copy of  your  `myTableViewController`, call it's `addCellToHome()` function, and then discard the newly created view controller without displaying it. That is wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Send a message from a button in a custom table view cell to the owning `UITableViewController`?

Comment: if you just need a single action from the whole cell just implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` on the delegate, no button required.

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you want. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My hunch is you're creating a new instance of `tableViewController` instead of using the current one that is in memory.  Try the following instead of creating a new instance of the VC.

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) { 
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"tableViewController") as! tableViewController
    myTableViewController?.addCellToHome(self) //call add function
}
```

If you plan on using this VC in other method calls, you can also initialize the the `myTableViewController` outside of any function in the class like you did in your original post.

Comment: Got error:  Value of type 'UITableViewController' has no member 'addCellToHome'

Comment: Change `as! UITableViewController` to `as! tableViewController`, or whatever you class name is. And make sure you change the `withIdentifier` portion of the `instantiate` method to your VC's id in the storyboard.

Comment: @qunayu Glad i could help!

Comment: That code is creating a new throw-away view controller on each button press as well. That does not make sense.

Comment: @DuncanC From the sounds of it, he already has this VC on the navigation stack.  Using this code does not create a new instance of the VC, it's using the one that is in memory.  The OP's original code he was using _WAS_ creating a new instance of it, hence his function call was not working.

Comment: No, you are wrong. The function `instantiateViewController()` **always** creates a new instance of a view controller. The word "instantiate" means to create an instance.

Comment: @DuncanC Then why did this work and his original code not?  I understand what you're saying, but I learned this is the correct way to use a currently stacked VC.  Is there a better or more correct way?

Comment: @DuncanC  Provide an answer then because I have been doing it this way for 3 years and it works.  So what should be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129082/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-thevalyreangroup).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either make a delegate protocol for the cell, something like `MyCellDelegate`.

[See guide to delegates](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/).

Or add an action to the cells button from `cellForRow(at: IndexPath)` in your tableViewController.

[See guide to button actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894765/ios-swift-button-action-in-table-view-cell)