# In SWTableViewCell, UtilityButtons not responding to setTag Property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, nsindexpath

I am using SWTableViewCell to override Standard TableViewCell to show its swipeable Left & Right Utility Buttons, 
I am able to access storyboard segue or I am able to segue to detailViewController.

However I've issue with utility buttons `setTag` Property

How can I access UitlityButtons row's IndexPath whereas I've already tried following.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; 
NSLog(@"selected favourite button tag %ld",(long)indexPath);
```

In simulator it gives me same result each time for each of the row.

> selected favourite button tag 0

Any solution to get button's "`setTag`" property to access index path of the row for those utility buttons in SWTableViewCell when pressed just like in normal tableview

or

How to access setTag Property of Utility buttons to access indexPath of the row containing that specific button when pressed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894765/ios-swift-button-action-in-table-view-cell

Comment: There must be a delegate method in which you will get the selected row.

Comment: indexPath.row or indexPath.section, not indexPath.

Comment: There is only alert view displaying in that delete message without any reference to that row @Mind_Sparkles

Comment: @Sneak , already tried indexPath.row method but showing something in (long) formate but same number for each & every row. which means it is not showing expected result.

Comment: you have to set a delegate of cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make use of `SWTableViewCellDelegate`. While returning the cell in the `cellForRow` method of `UITableViewDataSource` set the delegate of the cell to be your view controller (`cell.delegate = self`) and implement the `SWTableViewCellDelegate` protocol.

**SWTableViewCellDelegate:**

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

In either of these two delegate methods you may access the `indexPath` of the cell whose utitlity button is pressed ike so:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"Index path: %@", indexPath);
```

Here you have the `indexPath`.