# How to get rowIndex by switchButton of TableCellView "Custom"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm building a simple TableViewController, with a Custom TableViewCell.

In this TableViewCell I have

1) ImageView
2) Label
3) Switch Button

Now for example I have when I try to start my application 5 row.
I want to start a method if the user click on switch button of one of the rows items.

So I  have build this method:

```
@IBAction func attivaLuci(sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.on {
            //ATTIVO LA LUCE CORRISPONDENTE
        }else{
            //DISATTIVO LA LUCE CORRISPONDENTE
        }
    }
```

now how can I get the rowIndex of the cell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift Button action in table view cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894765/ios-swift-button-action-in-table-view-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 let row = sender.convert(sender.frame.origin, to: self.tableview)
 let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForRow(at: row)
```

or simply

```
switchbutton.tag = indexPath.row
@IBAction func attivaLuci(sender: UISwitch) 
{
  let rowindex = sender.tag      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can use *tag* property. Any subclass of UIView can use this property to distinguish an object from another.

like you can set buttonA.tag = 101 and buttonB.tag = 102 when they are created. when you want distinguish them just write : if(button.tag == 101).

- or you can distinguish them by cell, using indexPath.row

Answer (score 0):

In Swift an easy and smart way is a callback closure.

In the custom cell declare a variable `callback`

```
var callback : ((Bool) -> ())?
```

and call the method in the `IBAction`

```
@IBAction func attivaLuci(sender: UISwitch) {
   callback?(sender.isOn)
}
```

In the table view controller in `cellForRowAt` set the callback

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell...
   ...
      cell.callback = { isOn in
        // execute code, the index path is captured.
        // isOn is the current state of the switch
      }
   ...
  }
```

When the `IBAction` in the custom cell is called the closure of the callback is executed.