# Recursive UITableViewCell button Action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm able to generate a `UITableView` and a `UITableViewCell` however my action is not working properly. My use case is similiar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6Wl8ySrOZI)

I was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894765/ios-swift-button-action-in-table-view-cell) question as a reference and was uncesscessful

What am I missing? Something swift 3 related?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var categories = ["foo", "bar"]

    func logAction(sender: UIButton!){
        print("HIT BUTTON YO")
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.categories.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {      
        let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categories", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.label.text = categories[indexPath.row]
        let button = cell.button
        button?.tag = indexPath.row
        button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.logAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return(cell)
    }
}


class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        //Configure view for selected state
    } 
}
```

Comment: what does crash log says if any?

Comment: it doesnt crash at all....When I click on the button on my table, nothing happens....have also tried `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a smarter way to handle a button action in a custom cell.

In the custom cell create a callback closure with no parameter / no return value and an `IBAction` connected to the button. In the action call the callback

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var callback : (()->())?

    @IBAction func logAction(_ sender : UIButton) {
        callback?()
    }
}
```

In `cellForRow` assign a closure to the callback, the index path is captured.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categories", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.label.text = categories[indexPath.row]
    cell.callback = {
        print("Button pressed", indexPath)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Note: `return` is not a function (no parentheses).

Comment: No response from the console with that, it does look clean though

Comment: Is the class of the custom cell set to `CustomCell` in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes it is. Not sure what else it could be

Comment: Works like a charm for me... maybe start fresh?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the cell's button directly. Instead of

```
let button = cell.button
button?.tag = indexPath.row
button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.logAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Set the properties on the button directly.

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.logAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: No response from the console with that

Comment: it looks like your "#selector(self.logAction)" could be wrong. It should look like "logAction(sender:)".

Answer (score 0):

yea so I just deleted the view controller and remade and it works now ¯_(ツ)_/¯