# How to get selected table view cell row in segue?

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, segue, indexpath

I am developing an iOS app using Swift and I have a view controller that segues from a table view cell content view by selecting a cell row or selecting a button inside of that cell row's content view. The original view controller that contains the table view performs a segue on two different occasions: one segue when the cell row itself is selected (segues to an avplayerviewcontroller and plays a video depending on the cell row that was selected) and the second segue happens when you press a button that is inside of the content view of the table view cell. In the first segue, I am able to pass the the cell row that is selected with `if let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow` when I override the first segue. However when I try to pass the cell row that was selected when I try to override the second segue that happens when you press the button it doesn't work. Is this because the button inside of the table view cell doesn't know which row it was selected in? If so, how can I solve this problem, and if not what is a viable solution to solve such issue? Reminder: The "playDrill" segue is trigged when you select a cell row, the "Tips" segue is trigged when you selected a button inside of that same cell row's content view

Code for first segue that happens when you select a cell row (this segue functions as desired):

```
class DrillsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "playDrill" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            if initialRow == 1 {
                drillVid = videoURL[indexPath.row]
                playerViewController = segue.destination as! PlayerController
                playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: drillVid))
                playerViewController.player?.play()
                print(indexPath) //prints correct value which is "[0,6]"
            }
            if initialRow == 3 {
                drillVid = videoUrl[indexPath.row]
                playerViewController = segue.destination as! PlayerController
                playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: drillVid))
                playerViewController.player?.play()
            }
```

Code for second segue that triggers when you select a button inside of the cell's content view (I want this segue to have the value of `indexPath` as in the first segue, but when I try to use that code it doesn't return the correct value):

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Tips" {
       if let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        if initialRow == 1 {
            print(indexPath)  //the value printed is "6", I want "[0,6]" like the first code block
            let tipVC = segue.destination as! KeysController

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think by writing so much you made your question seem way more confusing than it has to be. Where's the code for the button's IBAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to get the selected index of the selected cell because **you are not actually selecting a cell**. You are pressing a button inside the cell.

So, what you do is get a reference to the button, get the button's superview (the cell) and then you can get the `indexPath` of that cell.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var indexPathForButton: IndexPath?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let button = sender
        let cell = button.superview!.superview! as! MyCell  // The number of levels deep for superviews depends on whether the button is directly inside the cell or in a view in the cell
        indexPathForButton = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    }
```

---

Then in `prepare(for segue:)`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Tips" {
        if initialRow == 1 {
          print(indexPathForButton)
          let tipVC = segue.destination as! KeysController
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed, green checked and up-voted.

Comment: Where does the first block of code go? I don't have a table view controller. I have a table view inside of a view controller.

Comment: Put it in the view controller class. Do you already have an IBAction for your button?

Comment: No I do not. The IBAction for the button is located in the table view cell swift file since the button lies in the content view of the cell table view.

Comment: @MarkoCain See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28895402/3746301 regarding setting tags.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also a couple of months ago... finally I was able to solve it with the following tasks:

1. Create an Outlet and Action of the button in your corresponding `TableViewCell`
2. Create a `XYTableViewCellDelegate` protocol in your `TableViewCell.swift` file
3. Define a delegate of your previous created `TableViewCell` delegate in your `TableViewCell` class
4. Define your delegate in `cellForRowAt:` function of your tableview
5. Add the delegate to your ViewController class where the TableView is also implemented
6. Finally just create this function in your ViewController to receive the tapped buttons tableview indexpath

If you need more help on this, please just copy / paste your whole ViewController & TableViewCell class here - We can make then the changes directly in the code.

---

It should look like the following code:

```
// FILE VIEWCONTORLLER
// -> 5.
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, XYTableViewCellDelegate {

  // ... view did load stuff here

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell:TripDetailsTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

      // -> 4.
      cell.delegate = self

    // ... 
  }

  // -> 6.
  func buttonTappedViewCellResponse(cell: UITableViewCell) {
     let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
     // do further stuff here
  }
}


// FILE TABLEVIEWCELL
// -> 2.
protocol XYTableViewCellDelegate {
    func buttonTappedViewCellResponse(cell:UITableViewCell)
}
class XYTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  // -> 1.
  @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

  // -> 3.
  var delegate: XYTableViewCellDelegate?

  // -> 1.
  @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.buttonTappedViewCellResponse(cell: self)
  }
}
```

Comment: Above the code I listed the todos 1 - 6. The arrows in the code are pointing to the corresponding listing item

Comment: so in case of // -> 1. I mean my listing 1. Create an Outlet and Action of the button in your corresponding TableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow` (and while I think it is not good practice, I am not sure if it is responsible for your issue), however one other approach you might try is to send the `indexPath` object as `sender`. This would avoid having to check for `tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow` inside `prepareForSegue`. For instance,

- You can trigger your `"playDrill"` segue in `tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)` where you have access to this `indexPath` and can simply pass it as `sender`.
- When triggering your `"Tips"` segue, you can also pass this `indexPath` object as sender. One way to have a reference is to keep the `indexPath` object when you dequeue your cell and set the button action in `ableView(UITableView, willDisplay: UITableViewCell, forRowAt: IndexPath)`

Let me know if that helps you! Cheers,

Julien

Comment: Could you link me to or supply some code that implements your answer? It sounds valid, however I'm having a little trouble following since I am a newbie to Swift! Your answer is greatly appreciated!