# Changing image of a button in UITableViewCell on clicking it.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an app in which, the image of the **UIButton** in **UITableViewCell** should change on **click** and I have done this in a **custom cell**. Right now, I am able to change the image of the button but it is also changing the image of few other buttons too as I scroll down (as `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called on scrolling).

Here is the code.

```
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        _cell = (ListTableViewCell *)[self.tblList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"listTableViewCell"];
        if (_cell == nil) {
            _cell = [[ListTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"listTableViewCell"];
        } else {
            _cell.imgIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
            _cell.lblList.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            _cell.btnList.tag = indexPath.row;
            if (_cell.btnList.tag == indexPath.row) {
                [_cell.btnList addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressedMethodCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
        }
        return _cell;
    }


- (void) btnPressedMethodCall:(UIButton*)sender  {
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

Could someone please tell how this problem can be solved. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Check this link [Tableview button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894765/uibutton-action-in-table-view-cell/41374087#41374087)

Comment: the tableview needs a datasource to display data. Once you change the button attributes, you need to update table datasource, so the tableview will display properly.

Comment: please reload uitableviewcell on your Action - btnPressedMethodCall

Comment: Set  both states image initially and just call `[sender setSelected:NO/YES]` on button click. You will also need to handle this in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as this methods calls on scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing image in button click event. Add selected `button` `indexPath` in `NSMutableArray` and in `cellForRow` method check `NSMutableArray` contain current `indexPath`. if yes than change `button` image else set normal image like below.

**Swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = self.tblVW.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    if arrIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.btn.setImage(YOUR_BUTTON_SELECTED_IMAGE, for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        cell.btn.setImage(YOUR_BUTTON_DEFAULT_IMAGE, for: .normal)
    }
    cell.layoutSubviews()
    return cell;
}

@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    arrIndexPaths.add(selectedIndexPath)
    self.tblVW.reloadData()
}
```

If you want to reload only single row than replace `self.tblVW.reloadData()` with `self.tblVW.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)`

**Objective C**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if ([arrIndexPaths containsObject: indexPath]) {
        [cell.btn setImage:YOUR_BUTTON_SELECTED_IMAGE forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [cell.btn setImage:YOUR_BUTTON_DEFAULT_IMAGE forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [cell layoutSubviews];
    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)btnTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
    [arrIndexPaths addObject:selectedIndexPath];
    [self.tblVW reloadData];  // Reload Whole TableView

    //OR
    NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:selectedIndexPath, nil];
    [self.tblVW reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; // Reload Single Row
}
```

Comment: whole tableview reload that is bad idea but reload only one cell

Comment: @AkshayDegada: for single cell reload : `self.tblVW.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none) // SINGLE SELECTED BUTTON CELL RELOAD`

Comment: This is Swift, question is tagged with `objective-c`

Comment: @Koen, now is it fine?

Comment: @Kuldeep thanks followed your Swift answer thanks for posting objective-c version too, it works now.