# clicking a button inside table view

Tags: ios, swift

i have a table view with a custom cell that has a button .. if i clicked on the button an action should be done ..

the problem is that the button is not cliked and the whole cell is clicked and the action i want never happen!

how to solve that? i want to click on the button not the cell and do specific action when clicked..

here what i'm doing but didnt work..

the custom cell:

```
 class CustomViewCell8: UITableViewCell {

var onButtonTapped : (() -> Void)? = nil
@IBOutlet weak var servicebtn: UIButton!

@IBAction func Clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let onButtonTapped = self.onButtonTapped{
        onButtonTapped()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}


override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

and in the view controller:

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell8") as! CustomViewCell8
    cell.servicebtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: serviceimage[indexPath.row]) as UIImage?, for: UIControlState.normal)

    cell.onButtonTapped = {
        if self.number == 1 {
            if indexPath.row == 0{
                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: " ") as UIViewController
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "services") as! Data
                let decodedService = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Service]

                for service in decodedService {
                    if service.name == " "{
                        GetShiftsAndPrices(id: service.id)
                    }
                }
            }else if indexPath.row == 1{
                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: " ") as UIViewController
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "services") as! Data
                let decodedService = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Service]

                for service in decodedService {
                    if service.name == " "{
                        GetShiftsAndPrices(id: service.id)

                    }
                }
            }else if indexPath.row == 2{
                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: " ") as UIViewController
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "services") as! Data
                let decodedService = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Service]

                for service in decodedService {
                    if service.name == " "{
                        GetShiftsAndPrices(id: service.id)


                    }
                }
            }

       ......
    return cell
}
```

this was working with me before .. but now not working! i don't know what is wrong .. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894765/uibutton-action-in-table-view-cell

Comment: Does the code for all 3 rows do the same thing? Why are you passing " " for the identifier when creating the `UIViewController`s?

Comment: @vacawama no not the same i just deleted the name of the id's

Comment: Is that the only difference between the rows?

Comment: @vacawama yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated that even a `print("here")` in your `@IBAction` for the button isn't printing.  You also indicated that your `@IBAction` was wired up correctly.  That means there is a problem with your prototype cell.  If the view containing the button is smaller than the button, then you won't be able to click it.  Check the layout of your prototype cell.

**Original Answer**

That looks like it should work.

Three comments:

1. You should add `[unowned self]` to your closure declaration to avoid a *strong reference loop* which will prevent the `UITableView` from being freed.  Since the cell will not outlive its containing `UITableView`, there is no need for it to hold a strong reference to `self`.

   ```
   cell.onButtonTapped = { [unowned self]
       if self.number == 1 {
       ...
   ```
2. You can use *optional chaining* to replace:

   ```
   if let onButtonTapped = self.onButtonTapped{
      onButtonTapped()
   }
   ```

   with simply:

   ```
   self.onButtonTapped?()
   ```
3. You code is very repetitive.  If the only difference between the rows is the *identifier* for the next ViewController, then you could do:

   ```
   let nextvcid = ["foo", "bar", "baz"][indexPath.row]

   cell.onButtonTapped = { [unowned self]
       if self.number == 1 {
           let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: nextvcid)
           self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
           let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
           let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "services") as! Data
           let decodedService = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Service]

           for service in decodedService {
               if service.name == " "{
                   GetShiftsAndPrices(id: service.id)
               }
           }
   ```

Comment: this is won't solve it :(( i even tried      cell.onButtonTapped = { 
               print("hi")
        } but still nothing happend!! i have no idea what the problem is T_T

Comment: Did you wire up your `@IBAction` to your button? Put a `print("here")` in your button code to make sure it is being hit.

Comment: just did.. and it is not printed :|

Comment: Option-click on your button in your prototype cell.  Does it have an action connected to *touchUpInside*?

Comment: yes it have T_T its Clicked in the customcell controller .. i really don't know what is missing?

Comment: How is your cell configured?  It is possible that user interaction is disabled for a containing view of the button?

Comment: how can i know that?

Comment: user interaction is enabled for the custom cell

Comment: The problem almost has to be your prototype cell.  One possibility is that the containing view for the button is smaller than the button

Comment: yeah thats true!!! that was the problem it was bigger!!! THANK YOUU SOOO MUCHH!!!!! T_T

Comment: You're welcome.  Please take a look at the other comments in my answer.  They're still important.  Please accept my answer when you get a chance.