# instantiate a storyboard from a button press inside a collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm trying to instantiate a storyboard from a button press inside a collection view cell but am coming across errors:

```
class sampleCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBAction func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InputViewController") as! InputViewController//error: Use of undeclared type "InputViewController"

        present(vc, animated: false)//error:Use of unresolved identifier 'present'
    }
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You don't have a class named `InputViewController`

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InputViewController") as! InputViewController
```

2- You can't present a vc inside a cell , you need a delegate

```
present(vc, animated: false)
```

---

A note only for main storyboard you can substitute

```
UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

with ( But inside a vc also )

```
self.storyboard
```

**Edit:** ---------------------------------------------------------

inside the cell

```
class sampleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  weak var delegate:CurrentController?
}
```

Then inside `cellForItemAt`

```
let cell = /////
cell.delegate = self
```

Add to the vc

```
func goToInput() {

    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InputViewController") as! InputViewController//error: Use of undeclared type "InputViewController" 
    present(vc, animated: false) 

}
```

After that inside cell action

```
@IBAction func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
  delegate?.goToInput()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the error because the `present(_:animated:completion:)` is a UIViewController instance method, but not a UITableViewCell.

So, what you should instead is to figure out a way to handle the button action in the view controller that contains the table view instead of trying to present a view controller from the cell class.

Considering that you would follow the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28895402/5501940

you would be able to call the present method in the button selector method:

```
@objc func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InputViewController") as! InputViewController
    present(vc, animated: false)
}
```

Also, make sure that you have a `InputViewController` view controller.