# Which component of the cell was touched

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a cell with 2 images in it. When the user touches a particular image I want to use `NSLog` to state which image was clicked.

For now, I am only getting the cell that was selected. How can I get which image was touched too?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"CELL CLICKED WAS %ld",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: You can add `TapGestures` on the images, and handle it separately. Can't be handled in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` though.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell/20655223#20655223, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own custom UITableviewCell.

In it implement `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`.

In `touchesBegan`, you can get a `touch` object, get it's location and see if it is inside the `UIImage`.

Something like this.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [aTouch locationInView:self.superview];
CGRect imageRect = myImage.frame;
if(CGRectContainsPoint(imageRect,touchPoint)
{
NSLog(@"here");
}

}
```

Comment: Easy is to add TapGesture without Custom Cell, though your solution will also work..

Comment: @iphonic yup you my good sir are correct. If I use gestures, how would I know which gesture came from which image of which cell? Tags maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add any `UIControl` over your images separately to know which image is selected like:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouched)];
[yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

and

```
-(void)imageTouched{
    NSLog(@"Image 1 Clicked");
}
```

Do the same for second Image.....!!

Comment: Can't i do this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath ` ?

Comment: no man `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is the delegate for tableview so will only work when u select the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tap gesture recognizer on each image while creating cell as

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = nil;
    tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnImageA:)];
    [cell.imageViewA addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];

    tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnImageB:)];
    [cell.imageViewB addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
```

and implement the gesture events for each image as-

```
    - (void) handleTapOnImageA:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
        if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
            NSLog(@"Image A Touched");
        }
    }

- (void) handleTapOnImageB:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
        if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
            NSLog(@"Image B Touched");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you need `Location` sir?

Comment: thanks Sir for reviewing my code and pointing the need for Location, yes there was no need of accessing location there.