# Custom cell UITextField updated in all cells across all sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicontrolevents

This is a dynamic prototype UITableView: In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

1. I have dequequed my custom cell and this works just fine:

   ```
   TimeSetViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"timeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   ```
2. Next I set TimePicker to UITextField in timeCell and this works fine as well (i.e. the time picker displayed onclick of UITextField in `timeCell`) :

   ```
   // Start Time
   UIDatePicker *sTimePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
   sTimePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
   sTimePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]
   [cell.startTripTime setInputView:sTimePicker];

   // End Time
   UIDatePicker *eTimePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
   eTimePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
   eTimePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [cell.endTripTime setInputView:eTimePicker];
   ```
3. Next I wanted to update the cell's UITextField through an event, in which I have understood from [@Mani's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20655223/1833191), I have set:

   ```
   sTimePicker.tag = 1;
   eTimePicker.tag = 2;

   [sTimePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   [eTimePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   ```

   And in my custom method `-(void)updateTextField:(UIDatePicker *)sender` I have included this:

   ```
   //Date Formatter
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [dateFormat setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

   if(sender.tag == 1){

       //Get Start Date
       UIDatePicker *starttimepicker = (UIDatePicker*)sender.inputView;
       thisStartTime = [starttimepicker date];

       //Display Date
       NSString *startTimeText = [dateFormat stringFromDate:thisStartTime];
       sTimeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",startTimeText];

   }
   if(sender.tag == 2){
       //Get End Date
       UIDatePicker *endtimepicker = (UIDatePicker*)sender.inputView;
       thisEndTime = [endtimepicker date];

       //Display Date
       NSString *endTimeText = [dateFormat stringFromDate:thisEndTime];
       eTimeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",endTimeText];
   }
   ```

## Question Update

1. I managed to pass `startTimeText` and `endTimeText` to `cell.startTripTime.text` and `cell.endTripTime.text` through `sTimeText` and `eTimeText`.
2. And I used `[_tableView reloadData];` in `-(void)updateTextField:(UIDatePicker *)sender` (after the two *if* blocks) and the data is displayed in my `cell.startTripTime`and `cell.endTripTime` UITextField, but it appears the same in across of my sections, while I want it to change only the first section's time, **how** can I fix that?

   ```
   //I couldn't include the image but the output of the UITableView looks like this:

   _________________________
   Section 1
   _________________________
   Start Time : 4:50 PM
   _________________________
   End Time: 5:50 PM
   _________________________
   Section 2
   _________________________
   Start Time : 4:50 PM
   _________________________
   End Time: 5:50 PM
   _________________________
   ```
3. And the `[_tableView reloadData];` seems to interfere and reloads the view while I haven't even finish picking the time that I wanted, **how** can I fix this too?

Answer (score 0):

The action method should be sent to one of the picker, the startStripTime seems to be a UIView instance not a UIDatePicker instance.
It is he date picker that changes its value, not the view containing it.
You should change also the update method accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, I noticed it should have been `-(void)updateTextField:(UIDatePicker *)sender` and I have already changed it in my post. By the way I have set the inputView of `startTripTime`, that makes it a time (date) picker (I got my reference from [here](http://www.codingexplorer.com/replace-keyboard-with-uidatepicker/) ). But next problem is that how am I able to change the text of my `cell.startTripTime` UITextField in respond to that event?

Comment: I see, you rewrite inputView by setting it to the date piker instance. I thought it was a custom setter to add the pick as a subview to a container view. But now I don't get it the -updateTextField is called

Comment: Now i understood your first comment and changed to this- action sent to a time picker (sTimePicker): `[sTimePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`, sorry for that. So now: in `-updateTextField` setting the text `sender.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",startTimeText];` should be replaced with `cell.startTripTime.text` _but_ `cell` was initialised in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` not in `-updateTextField`, how can I pass the "startTimeText" to "cell.startTripTime.text" ?

Comment: Why don't you create the pickers inside the cell? and add the cell as the target for the action of the picker, so you can reference the cell text field from the inside (or we are talking about a cell not related to the picker cell). I don't understand the patter that you are applying and what you want to achieve. Maybe a picture of your UI would help.

Comment: Hmm, let me explain how it looks like since I do not have enough reputations to include an image. [1] In my _UITableView_, I have this custom cell ( _UITableViewCell_ class _TimeSetViewCell_ , identifier _timeCell_) [2] In that cell I have two _UITextField_  for _starttime_ and _endtime_ [3] Each time I click on the _UITextField_ in that cell, it displays a _UIDatePicker_ in which I have set the format to be a time picker (this works) [4] When I select a time from the picker the _UITextField_ should update itself with the time I have selected in text.

Comment: I have used `NSLog` to track the changes from my picker by printing `startTimeText`, and the selected time is logged e.g. 5: 40 PM (this part works too). I just couldn't pass `startTimeText` to my `cell.startTripTime.text` for it to be displayed. Do I need to use `[_tableView reloadData]`?

Comment: If you save the string result from the date picker in an ivar of the view controller (that i guess is the delegate/datasource of the tvc), then you can pass it to the cell by calling reloadData

Comment: Andrea, be it iVar or global Variable it works just fine, I have tried and thanks it works! Now that I have a more severe question in my **Question Update** above, do you have any idea on how to work on it?

Comment: @F.Lee please do not update the original question with another question, just create a bran new question.

Comment: Alright noted, will go along the convention next time. For now, I guess I shall further investigate into my own question and hope that I could find a workaround and share a solution. Thanks for all your help and advices all the while Andrea, appreciate it.