# Presenting a View Controller with a button in a UITableViewCell programmatically (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to make it where when a user clicks on a table view cell in my table view it takes them to a new view controller. More specifically, when a user clicks on a persons username it should take them to that users profile. the username being the table view cell and the profile being the new view controller. I thought the way to do this was to use the ".presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) however when i do this it says "myCell does not have a member named .presentViewController"[image: Below is a screenshot of the issue]

If anyone could help me solve this problem it'd be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 21):

The `presentViewController:animated:completion` is an instance method of the `UIViewController` not `UIView` or a subclass of. You can try this:

```
self.window?.rootViewController.presentViewController(specificViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, I suggest that you should use the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method from `UIViewController`. A callback mechanism can be achieved between the `UIViewController` and the `cell`.

Like so:[Get button click inside UI table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell)

Answer (score 12):

Banning's answer works, however the syntax is old. From **Swift 4**:

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

`swift3` version

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)
let messagesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(messagesViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a **separate** class for `tableView` which is a good practice then, you can do it like this:

First, create **addTarget** where the cell is created (cellForRowAt):

```
cell.dropdownBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openListPickerVC(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

After that, present view controller in openListPickerVC():

```
@objc func openListPickerVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let index = sender.tag
    let vc: PickerViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: 
             Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
             "PickerViewController") as! PickerViewController

     self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```