# Presenting a UIViewController with a button or UIImageview in a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift3, tableview

I am trying to make it when the users clicks on  Button in a table view cell  it takes them to a new view controller related to the current cell.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736391/presenting-a-view-controller-with-a-button-in-a-uitableviewcell-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Presenting a View Controller with a button in a UITableViewCell programmatically (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736391/presenting-a-view-controller-with-a-button-in-a-uitableviewcell-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

Do this in cellForRowAt indexPath,

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell_Identifier", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapMyButton(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    return cell
            }
```

And here is the button action,

```
func didTapMyButton(_ sender : UIButton) {
    let selectedIndex = sender.tag // You can get index here, so according to the index you can navigate to particular ViewController
    let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UIViewController_identifier") as! UIViewController
    self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope it helps ..