# Getting indexPath from switch on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView set up with custom cells in it. Each cell has a switch in it and I need to get the indexPath of a specific cell every time a switch is interacted with. How can I return the indexPath of a cell from a UITableView with custom cells each time a switch is interacted?

Comment: Did you create your cell programmatically, or through IB?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The cells were created making an .xib file and linking it to a subclass of UITableViewCell where I set everything up, and then I used the tableview methods to populate the table with cells (not sure if this is the answer you were looking for so let me know)

Comment: If you have a single section, you could set the `Tag` property of the switch to the row of the index path when you populate the table with cells.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get button click inside UI table view cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `indexPathForRowAtPoint` like:

```
@IBAction func switchChanged(sender: UIControl) {
    let rowPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(rowPoint)
    println(indexPath)
}
```

This is the Objective C version

```
- (IBAction)toggleSwitch:(id)sender {
     UISwitch *switchInCell = (UISwitch *)sender;
     CGPoint pos = [switchInCell convertPoint:switch.bounds.origin toView:tableView];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pos];
}
```

If you want to get the cell's indexPath in your custom cell:

```
// CustomCell.swift
@IBAction func switchChanged(sender: UIControl) {
    let tableView = self.tableView()
    let indexPath = tableView?.indexPathForCell(self) 
    println(indexPath)
}

func tableView() -> UITableView? {
    var tableView = self.superview
    while (tableView != nil && !(tableView is UITableView)) {
        tableView = tableView!.superview
    }

    return tableView as? UITableView
}
```

Comment: But this does seem like the best option.

Comment: Since my tableView is in a different class than my custom cell's class, how do I deal with the  `toView: self.tableView` in `sender.convertPoint`?

Comment: @ACR Do you want to get indexPath inside the cell?

Comment: I want to get the indexPath of the cell in the tableView. This is because in my app I have a tableView of 8 cells which corresponds to the 8 switches in the tableView.

Comment: @Bannings This returns nil every time I interact with the switch.

Comment: @ACR I have fixed the issue for the loop

Comment: @Bannings It's still returning nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81650/discussion-between-bannings-and-acr).

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think to solve this is

**EDIT** This might work in iOS6 or older

```
- (void)toggleSwitch:(id)sender {
     UISwitch *switch = (UISwitch *)sender;
     UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*) switch.superview;
     NSIndexPath *indexpath = [[self yourTableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous. Different versions of iOS can have differing numbers of views between the sender and the cell.

Comment: @Bannings True, although could you not loop through its superviews and look for the UITableViewCell?

Comment: Yeah agree I just took it from an old project I have

Answer (score 0):

**One section TableView:**
in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set the tag of the current cell's switch something like `cell.switch.tag = indexPath.Row` and in your toggling method you can get the tag of your switch

```
- (void)toggleSwitch:(id)sender {
UISwitch *switch = (UISwitch *)sender;
int row = switch.tag;
//you can switch on the switch values to to get the exact switch then do your action 
}
```

**Multi sections tableView:**
Make a custom switch class that have a property `NSIndexPath` then in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set this property with the actual cell's indexpath, but don't forget to reset this property in `prepareForReuse` method in the custom cell.
and in your toggling method you will get the actual `indexPath`