# handle uibutton click in uitableview cause error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I've got a UITableViewCell that contains a button, I handle this button click event follow this link [Get button click inside UI table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell),

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            cell.directCommentButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.directCommentButton.addTarget(self, action: "directCommentButtonClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}

func directCommentButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    // directComment = 1
    println("DIRECT COMMENT")
}
```

but there is an error `directCommentButtonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9e50590f10'` and app has crashed. When I remove the sender: AnyObject, the error disappear, but I want to get the sender, how can I do that. Tks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass your action selector this way:

```
cell.directCommentButton.addTarget(self, action: "directCommentButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

you have to add `:` because your function accepts an argument.

Comment: tks so much, I've been searching for a day :))

Comment: Happy to help you..:)