# several labels within a cell in tableview (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

For example, there are 4 labels in a cell. when the user click on one of them. is there any ways to recognise which label is he clicking on?

if yes, by what function that can i get the text value of that labels?

Comment: If you are talking about a custom tableViewCell, set a tag on each label instance programmatically.

Comment: Add UITapGesture on each UILabel and in @selector you will get the taped label and its text

Answer (score 0):

You can add tap gesture on the labels. 
Here is [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/) and [Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2)

Answer (score 0):

[This question is for button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell). Same rule apply to label.

> 1) In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, assign label tag as index
>
> 2) Add target Action for label