# Get label from cell - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

Here is my code:

```
var username: String!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : MainCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainCell

    username = usernameLabel.text
    cell.button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapLabel(_:)))
    cell.button.addGestureRecognizer(tapButton)

    return cell as MainCell
}

func tapButton(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(username) //this prints the wrong cell... why?
}
```

i want to be able to print the variable username but it prints the wrong username for the cell when i press on the button. why is that and how can i fix it?

Comment: Why do you expect the correct value to be printed? `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called many times so `username` will only have the value of the last referenced cell. But you try to print that value for every cell.

Comment: why you used getsure for button , no need you can directly get the index

Comment: this also wrong username = usernameLabel.text

Comment: @rmaddy ohhh i see. then whats the solution?

Answer (score 1):

add tag in cellForRowAtIndex

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : MainCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainCell

     cell.button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.button.setTitle( usernameLabel.text, forState: .Normal)
     cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell as MainCell
}
```

get action as

```
func tapButton(sender: UIButton!) 
{
   username =  sender.titleLabel.text
    print(username)  
}
```

Comment: it means your cell prints the last value only, check the updated answer you get correct userName on click

Comment: It's poor practice to set a view's tag based on the cell's index path. That only works if there is one section and the rows are static (no adding, deleting, or reordering).

Comment: what's titleLabel.text?

Comment: it is a UIButton property  you can get the current index of text using button click,

Comment: @rmaddy - I agree brother, can you give any other suggest for this

Comment: `sender.` gives me this error: [UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f…….

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f…...

Comment: @johnniexo88 - can you update the question with my answer

Comment: @johnniexo88 - Something Mismatched bro, can you update the question once with answer

Answer (score 1):

you should implement action button in MainCell . you have available with username and this is best practice ;)

```
class MainCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UITextView!

   func tabButton(sender: AnyObject) {
       print(usernameLabel.text)
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will print the `latest value` stored in `username` because every `indexPath` of cell, it will update the value in `username` & at the end will give you the `latest updated value` no matter which cell you are `tapping`

Comment: then what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

1) In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, assign button tag as index:

```
cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

2) Add target and action for your button as below:

```
cell.yourbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.yourButtonClicked), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

3) Code actions based on index as below in ViewControler:

```
func yourButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        // Your code here

    }
}
```

Ref SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20655223/4033273

Comment: what the difference betewwn my answer and your answer

Comment: `if sender.tag == 0` gives me this error: [UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f…….

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f…...