# How to get Text from a label in custom cell in Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tbl_vw.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as!cuscellTableViewCell

    cell.txt_lbl.text = self.section[indexPath.row];
    cell.sel_btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return cell

}



func switchChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    let switchControl: UISwitch = sender as! UISwitch
    print("The switch is \(switchControl.on ? "ON" : "OFF")")

    if switchControl.on {
        print("The switch is on lets martch")
    }
}
```

I have a switch and a label in a custom cell in tableview. When I ON the switch i need to get the text in the label, can any one help how to make it possible.

Comment: Share some code related to custom cell, switch value changed action.

Comment: pkc456 i added some some codes.

Comment: I have added the solution code. @Arun please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tag property of UISwitch to store the position and use it in your handler to get the actual text form section array.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tbl_vw.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as!cuscellTableViewCell

    cell.txt_lbl.text = self.section[indexPath.row];

    cell.sel_btn.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.sel_btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return cell

}



func switchChanged(sender: AnyObject) 
{
  let switchControl: UISwitch = sender as! UISwitch
  print("The switch is \(switchControl.on ? "ON" : "OFF")")

  let text = self.section[switchControl.tag]
  print(text)

  if switchControl.on 
  {
        print("The switch is on lets martch")
  }
}
```

If you have multiple sections with multiple rows you can use a dictionary and store a tuple.

```
var items = [Int:(Int,Int)]()
...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tbl_vw.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as!cuscellTableViewCell

    cell.txt_lbl.text = self.section[indexPath.row];
    cell.sel_btn.tag = indexPath.row

    let tuple = (section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)
    self.items[cell.sel_btn.hashValue] = tuple
    cell.sel_btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return cell

}

func switchChanged(sender: AnyObject) 
    {
      let switchControl: UISwitch = sender as! UISwitch
      print("The switch is \(switchControl.on ? "ON" : "OFF")")

      let tuple = self.items[switchControl.hashValue]
      print(tuple.0)  // this is the section
      print(tuple.1) // this is the row

      if switchControl.on 
      {
            print("The switch is on lets martch")
      }
    }
```

Comment: In case of multiple sections in `UITableView`, It won't work.

Comment: Christina Abella how can i achieve the same functionality in case of Multiple Sections.

Comment: @Arun Combine section and row by multiplying section * 100: `let tag = (indexPath.section + 1) * 100 + indexPath.row` and back `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tag % 100, inSection: (tag / 100) - 1)` An extra array is not needed.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to use it in a table with multiple sections and rows, use the hashValue of the control as key and store the section in row in a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

In your case move `func switchChanged(sender: AnyObject)` to your custom class and assign selector in customCell for `UISwitch`. You will start receiving your switchChange event in your customCell now you are customCell you have access to your `UISwitch` & `UILabel` objects, also keep a boolean flag to maintain switch state if required.

- **Step 1**: Move your `switchChanged` to customCell class.
- **Step 2**: In customCell `awakeFromNib` or `init` method assign selector to `UISwitch` object to cell itself to receive switch change event in cell.
- **Step 3**: Once your switch change event fires update your `UILabel` as you have access to it inside customCell.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Dipen tanks i will check it

Answer (score 0):

Set `tag` of `sel_btn`(UISwitch) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
sel_btn.tag = indexPath.row
```

On `switchChanged` method, get the tag of `sel_btn` and thus text of label.

```
let switchControl: UISwitch = sender as! UISwitch
        let tag = switchControl.tag
        let cell : cuscellTableViewCell = tbl_vw.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: tag, inSection: 0)) as? cuscellTableViewCell
        print(cell.txt_lbl.text)
```

If you want to get data from model not from view, then override the above two lines with below line:-

```
let textValue = self.section[tag];
```

Comment: In case of multiple sections in `UITableView`, It won't work.

Comment: In case of multiple sections, set the `tag = section + (10*row)`.

Comment: **Do not** get the text from the view (the cell) get it from the model (the data source)

Comment: print(cell.txt_lbl.text) getting a error value of type "uitableview cell " has no member "txt_lbl.text"

Comment: Write this:- `let cell : cuscellTableViewCell = tbl_vw.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: tag, inSection: 0)) as? cuscellTableViewCell`

Comment: again getting a error use of unresolved identifier tag.

Comment: Replace `tag` with `switchControl.tag` in above line.

Comment: Thanks for your effort pKc456

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is use block

from [Get button click inside UI table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell)

first move your action method to table  cell

in tableview cell add block property

```
 @property (copy, nonatomic) void (^didTapButtonBlock)(id sender);
```

with your action method

call block

```
- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    if (self.didTapButtonBlock)
    {
        self.didTapButtonBlock(sender);
    }
}
```

and receive that from cell , you have both section and row there

```
     [cell setDidTapButtonBlock:^(id sender)
     {
         // Your code here

     }];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
In tableview delegate method -

   tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)  

add index path value to switch tag value - 

cell.sel_btn.tag = indexPath.row


In Switch Value change method just get selected text when that switch is ON


func switchChanged(sender: AnyObject) 
{
  let switchControl: UISwitch = sender as! UISwitch
  print("The switch is \(switchControl.on ? "ON" : "OFF")")

  // If switch ON
  if switchControl.on 
  {
        print("The switch is ON”)

       // Get Selected Label Text
        let selectedText = self.section[switchControl.tag]
        print(selectedText)

  }
}
```

Comment: How to achieve this in table view with multiple section.

Comment: Maintain boolean array to show switch state in cellForRowAtIndexPath like :
cell.mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row
if (selectedFilterArray[indexPath.row] == "NO") {
    cell.mySwitch.on = false
}
else if (selectedFilterArray[indexPath.row] == "YES") {
    cell.mySwitch.on = true
}

Comment: In Value change Method  :

func switchChange(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    print("tag value \(Int(mySwitch.tag))")
    if mySwitch.on {
        print("tag value \(Int(mySwitch.tag))")
        print("textName \(self.section[mySwitch.tag])")
    }
    if !(selectedFilterArray[mySwitch.tag] == "NO") {
        //If checked
        mySwitch.on = true
    }
    else {
        //If not checked
        mySwitch.on = false
    }
}