# How to find out the position of the contentViews inside tableView cell?

Tags: swift3

I placed a view inside a  TableView Cell and have divided that view into 7 parts. Also, each view is assigned with a tag. Now, whenever I select a view, I want to find out the tag for identification and all I am getting is indexPath of the cell and details of all the views in it. 
How can I find out the exact location or tag of the selected view? Don't want to use gesture.  Can anyone help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

var cell = tableView?.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
     print(cell?.contentView.subviews)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What tag is that, you could get your cell properties normally after you got the cell.

```
if let cell = tableView?.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCellClass {
    tag = cell.tag
}
print(cell?.contentView.subviews)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, I don't want to find out the cell properties instead, I want to know which view is selected inside cell. I want to find out the particular tag of that view out of many other views inside cell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell

Maybe this is your need, just use buttons for you views.

Comment: Can't use button. Actually, I have added labels and image in views.