# UIButton move to storyboard in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'm trying to move to a new storyboard when a button is tapped in a custom cell type, but having trouble with the custom class. I currently have this

```
class submitCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }

}
```

and I need the cancelButton to do this

```
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TripList") as! TripTableViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil) //Move
```

Except that .present isn't a method of UITableViewCell, only UIViewController. How can I get this functionality to happen?

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this from a TableViewCell as it breaks MVC. You should really delegate the action to the tableViewController (or it's parent view controller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to call the function in your custom cell, do that in your view controller. Here is what you need

```
class submitCell: UITableViewCell {

    var tapAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
        tapAction?(self)
    }
}
```

and then in your view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    cell.tapAction = { [weak self] cell in self?.move()}
}

func move() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TripList") as! TripTableViewController
    self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil) //Move
}
```

Note: You should capitalise the first letter of your class name. Check out [Swift name conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

First in the custom cell, bring the button into it and connect.

```
class submitCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
}
```

And now lets do what you want to do in the class where you use the button.
In the class, where cell is created, do

```
cell.delegate = self
cell.cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

then create one function that does:

```
private func cancelAction(sender: UIButton){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TripList") as! TripTableViewController
    self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil) //Move
}
```

Comment: Im upvoting this.. I think you don't need to set the delegate, just add the target to the button.
From my perspective.. this is way better than protocols and delegation.

Comment: Also, don't forget to cast your cell to custom cell by "as! SubmitCell".

Answer (score 0):

There are a fews ways to do that.
- Create a delegate
- Create a reference for your button, so you can use in your ViewController.

I'll link some cases, so you can choice the best approach for your case:

## Reference Button

- [Get button click inside UI table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-ui-table-view-cell)

## Delegate

- https://www.codementor.io/leoiphonedev/delegates-in-swift-hvim2n7s1

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate the function cancelButton to the viewController by having a reference to the button in your custom cell class.

Basically, first you need to make an outlet to the button in your custom cell :

```
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
```

And then in your viewController :

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(cancelButton(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Declare the function :

```
    func cancelButton (_sender: UIButton) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TripList") as! TripTableViewController
    self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil) //Move
}
```

PS : If you have multiple buttons you can add them to the same action and control the behavior by a tag.

```
 button.tag = 0

 if ( _sender.tag == 0.) {
     // do tag 0
  } else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) pattern.

#### Create a protocol for your `UITableViewCell` delegate

```
protocol SubmitCellDelegate: class {
    func cancelButtonPressed()
}
```

#### Add the delegate to your `UITableViewCell` subclass

```
class SubmitCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: SubmitCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.cancelButtonPressed()
    }
}
```

#### Implement the delegate in your `UIViewController` subclass

This must be implemented in the class that has the reference to your tableview cell.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SubmitCellDelegate {

    // ... 
    // wherever you create your cell
        submitCell.delegate = self
    // ...

    // Implement the SubmitCellDelegate function (Xcode will force you to)
    func cancelButtonPressed() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TripList") as! TripTableViewController
        self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Side note: it's good practice in most (all?) object-oriented programming language to use title case on class names (e.g. `SubmitCell` instead of `submitCell`).