# When to remove a custom Click-Event from a UITableCellView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

in the past couple of days I have been optimizing my app and found some memory leaks.
I have implemented a custom `UIButton` that has a public event that I subscribe to. On one `UITableViewController` the button is hosted in a `UITableCellView` and I am subscribing to this event:

Cell:

```
class SelectionButtonCell : UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var selectionButton: SelectionButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

UITableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let selectionButtonCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selectionButtonCell") as! SelectionButtonCell
    selectionButtonCell.selectionButton.clicked = // This leaks memory because nowhere in my code this is set to nil
    {
        // Some unimportant stuff.
    }

    return selectionButtonCell
}
```

Button:

```
public class SelectionButton : UIButton
{
    // MARK: - Events
    public var clicked: (() -> ())?

    public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        self.clicked?()
    }
}
```

How do I set this var back to nil? I did not find any function that will be called when navigating back (the UITableViewController is pushed onto a `UINavigationController`).
Is it okay to simply iterate over all cells and set this back to nil in `viewWillDisappear(_)` or is there a nicer way?

I tried `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath` but it seems that this is only being called when scrolling the `UITableView`.

Comment: Can you show what's the definition for `clicked`?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the post and posted the definition of the event. I have stripped all other code for better readability.

Comment: Thanks. Just need to know why you haven't gone for `UIButton.addTarget` which would be safer option as the `IBOutlet`'s get automatically dealloc once the `UIViewController` is dismissed or pop.

Comment: How could I distinguish which cell was clicked then? The `sender` will give me the instance but not the index of the cell. Is it possible to use addTarget with a block or do I have to use a selector (probably the latter)?

Comment: There are various ways to do such task. Check this out already answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-uitableviewcell

Comment: Let me if you still need help.

Comment: Thank you, feel free to add your comments as an answer so I can accept them.

Comment: Thanks but SO doesn't accepts only link neither the question which already has the answer :) So, let me know if you have any issues I will surely help. Happy Coding :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let selectionButtonCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selectionButtonCell") as! SelectionButtonCell
        selectionButtonCell.selectionButton.clicked = 
        { [weak self] in
            // Some unimportant stuff.
        }

        return selectionButtonCell
    }
```

Also there are number of ways [Get button click inside UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655060/get-button-click-inside-uitableviewcell) you are using closure

Comment: Thanks, I used this solution because it works (deist is now called) and it is by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subclass of `UIButton`. And you don't need the `IBOutlet`

In `SelectionButtonCell` declare an `IBAction` and a callback. Connect the button to the action. In the callback pass the cell.

```
class SelectionButtonCell : UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var callback : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender : UIButton)
    {
        callback?(self)
    }
}
```

In `celForRow` get the current indexPath from the cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let selectionButtonCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selectionButtonCell") as! SelectionButtonCell
    selectionButtonCell.callback = { buttonCell in
        let actualIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: buttonCell)!
        ...
    }

    return selectionButtonCell
}
```

If cells in the tableview are not inserted, deleted or moved you don't even need the `cell` parameter in the callback closure. The captured `indexPath` parameter is still valid.